# HTML5 - URL characters stripped when using sms href

Tags: javascript, html, sms

I'm using the following format to open the SMS view on mobile phones from a browser

```
window.location.href = "sms:[phone number]?body=" + message;
```

I want to add the following google map URL in the SMS body

```
var myAddress = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=North+Miami,+FL+33190,+USA"
window.location.href = "sms:11122233333?body="+myAddress;
```

The SMS view opens fine on the phone and the SMS body is populated but the `+` signs are stripped out and replaced with spaces. I don't know what's causing this... How can this be prevented?

Comment: Does myAddress have quotations around it?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add them in the example. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encode the myAdress variable, before adding it to main url

```
    var myAddress = encodeURIComponent( "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=North+Miami,+FL+33190,+USA" );
    window.location.href = "sms:11122233333?body="+myAddress;
```

Comment: thanks I tried that but the `+` are still stripped in the SMS body on the phone.

Comment: myAddress.replace( /\+/g, '%2B' ) ) do anything for you?

Comment: sorry, no other ideas. according to RFC specs, the encoded string should work

Comment: @JohnSmith no, it still creates spaces

Comment: Then we will indiscriminately wipe them with replace( /\s/g, '+' ). Or how about replace( / /g, '%2B' )?